# Microsoft file synchronisation - only sync files with changes?

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Is it possible to only sync changes using this framework? I don't want to re sync the whole directory every time a file is added to be synced. I couldnt find any examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync will do incremental syncs, there's nothing special you need to do to get that working. It will only sync the changes since the last sync.The docs that comes with the framework has tutorials on how to do the sync.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can control how to detect which files are selected for synchronization with different flags in the FileSyncOptions object as well as the FileSyhncScopeFilter, e.g.,

```
   FileSyncOptions options =
        FileSyncOptions.CompareFileStreams |  
        FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
        FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates |
        FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

    FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
                    filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.exe");

    provider = new FileSyncProvider(replicaRootPath, filter, options);

    provider.DetectChanges();
```

CompareFileStreams requires additional overhead in that it compares hashes of files.  If this flag is not set only the file attributes are used.
See the MSDN page for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.files.filesyncoptions(v=sql.105).aspx